# How to find the volume of an ellipsoid using monte carlo integration

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am trying to find the volume of an ellipsoid using monte carlo integration by creating a function and am relatively new to this technique. I know how to plot the ellipsoid in 3D space using matplotlib and how to find the volume normally but am not sure how the monte carlo technique might apply for ellipsoid volume. Is there a sample code for how to go about doing this?

I have tried creating a function with the volume formula and repeating it for a large number of values, but am struggling to create a program that will do this.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special

def volume (a,b,c,n): #where a,b,c are the axis of the ellipsoid and n 
is the accuracy of the monte carlo integration
    volume= (4/3)*np.pi*a*b*c
```

Comment: (1) Create function to test if given coordinates lie in ellipsoid (2) Create random points all lying in a cuboid (in which the ellipsoid is enclosed) (3) Check how many points lie in ellipsoid (4) Divide hits by number of tried points and multiply with volume of cuboid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try to do this.

Comment: This method works really well- managed to create a function using the steps that calculates the volume. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def ellipsoid(x, y, z, a, b, c):
    return x**2/a**2 + y**2/b**2 + z**2/c**2

def V_ellipsoid(a, b, c, N):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(N):
        x = random.uniform(-a, a)
        y = random.uniform(-b, b)
        z = random.uniform(-c, c)
        if ellipsoid(x,y,z,a,b,c) <= 1:
            sum += 1
        volume = (sum/N)*(2*a)*(2*b)*(2*c)
    return volume
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The specific Monte Carlo technique is called rejection sampling. In this case you should sample a cube that contains full ellipsoid, calculate the ratio of number of points in an ellipsoid and in a cube, and multiply it by volume of the cube. Here's code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = 2
b = 3
c = 4

n_samples = 100000

x = np.random.uniform(-a, a, n_samples)
y = np.random.uniform(-b, b, n_samples)
z = np.random.uniform(-c, c, n_samples)

distance = (x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2 + (z/c)**2

n_ok = np.sum(distance < 1.)
volume_cube = 8. * a * b * c
volume = volume_cube * n_ok / n_samples
```

My code is similar to other reply, but faster (no `for` loop).

Answer (score 0):

Since i am trying to improve my knowledge in numpy, i will post a solution using the library, wich would be convenient in a 3D problem, that may require lots of points to converge:

```
import numpy as np

#Desided number of samples and parameters
samples = 500000
A = 1; B = 2; C = 3

#Function to decide if the points are inside de ellipsoid
ellipsoid = lambda x,y,z,a,b,c: ((x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2 + (z/c)**2)

#generating x,y,z coordinates of random points in a cube the enclosure the
#ellipsoid (the np.ceil is just to work with integers)
X = np.random.random(samples)*2*np.ceil(A) - np.ceil(A)
Y = np.random.random(samples)*2*np.ceil(B) - np.ceil(B)
Z = np.random.random(samples)*2*np.ceil(C) - np.ceil(C)

#points inside the ellipsoid
inside = (ellipsoid(X,Y,Z,A,B,C) <= 1).sum()

cube_area = np.ceil(A)*np.ceil(B)*np.ceil(C)*8

volume = (inside/samples)*cube_area

real_volume = (4/3)*np.pi*A*B*C

print(volume,real_volume)
```